# Como posso setar o endereço como logradouro e bairro correspondente a latitude e longitude?

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Tenho esse código:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode == MAPA_REQUEST_BAIRRO){
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                try {
                Place place = PlacePicker.getPlace(this, data);
                LatLng latLng = place.getLatLng();

                //txtLocalLogradouroB.setText(logradouro +"-"+ bairro);

                Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());
                List<Address> addresses1 = null;
                List<Address> addresses = null;

                double um= Double.parseDouble(latitude);
                double dois = Double.parseDouble(longitude);


                addresses1 = gcd.getFromLocation(um, dois, 1);

//                    }
                     if (addresses1.size() > 0) {
                    br = addresses1.get(0).getSubLocality();
                    lg = addresses1.get(0).getThoroughfare();
                    txtLocalLogradouroB.setText(lg + "-"+br);

                }
```

Mas ele não funciona. Tenho latitude e longitude que vem de uma webservice mas euq quero converter esses valores para pegar o endereço e mostrar para o usuário alguém poderia me ajudar por favor? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Geocoder geocoder;
List<Address> addresses;
geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
 try {
        addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1); // Here 1 represent max location result to returned, by documents it recommended 1 to 5
        String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0); // If any additional address line present than only, check with max available address lines by getMaxAddressLineIndex()
        String city = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
        String state = addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
        String country = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
        String postalCode = addresses.get(0).getPostalCode();
        String knownName = addresses.get(0).getFeatureName(); // Only if available else return NULL
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9409195/how-to-get-complete-address-from-latitude-and-longitude

Comment: não está funcionando

Comment: espera...só uma coisa aqui

Comment: eu preciso colocar esse código no oncreate é?

Comment: Não. Você cria essa classe somente quando precisar dela, se precisar.

Comment: Você leu os comentários das pessoas na pagina original dessa resposta?

Comment: Agora deu certo...mas eu nao criei classe nao. Coloquei no oncreate pq nesse metodo eu recebo os dados da webservice e seto

Comment: vou ler amigo. Espero saber procurar minhas perguntas...o problema é que nao sei ingles :(

Answer (score 2):

#### Opção 1:

Veja [alguns exemplos](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/android.location.Geocoder) de como você pode usar o Geocoder. Mas precisamente para o que você quer, tente usar a função abaixo que retorna o local baseado no `LatLng` passado:

```
/**
 * Obtem um endereço baseado LatLng
 * @param latitude e longitude do ponto que quer encontrar
 * @return local em relação ao ponto.
 */
public List<Address> getAddress(LatLng point) {
    try {
        Geocoder geocoder;
        List<Address> addresses;
        geocoder = new Geocoder(this);
        if (point.latitude != 0 || point.longitude != 0) {
            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(point.latitude ,
                    point.longitude, 1);
            String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
            String city = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1);
            String country = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(2);
            System.out.println(address+" - "+city+" - "+country);

            return addresses;

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "latitude and longitude are null",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return null;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

#### Opção 2:

Passar a `latitude` e `longitude` para a seguinte seqüência de consulta, e você terá um resultado em JSON:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=44.4647452,7.3553838&sensor=true
```

Depois disso<sup>([link](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=44.4647452,7.3553838&sensor=true))</sup>, é só interpretar o JSON e pegar somente as informações necessárias.

Detalhes na documentação [Google Maps Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro?hl=pt-br).

Comment: ahn? como faço isso/

Comment: não sei como fazer dessa forma

Answer (score -2):

vou fornecer um código que retorna o endereço e você pode editar para pegar as informações que quiser, mas ele é plugAndPlay. Vamos lá.

Declare estas variaveis antes do seu onCreate.

```
private lateinit var fusedLocationClient: FusedLocationProviderClient
private lateinit var lastLocation: Location
```

No onCreate inicialize esta variável:

```
 fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)
```

No método override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) { que o android Studio cria pra você, chame o seguinte método:

```
getUserLocation()
```

Agora vamos criar o método getUserLocation:

```
private fun getUserLocation (){
    // 1
    mMap.isMyLocationEnabled = true //libera buscar a localização do usuário

    // 2
    fusedLocationClient.lastLocation.addOnSuccessListener(this) { location -> //pega a localização
        // Got last known location. In some rare situations this can be null.
        // 3
        if (location != null) { //se encontrou algo, vai marcar a posição no mapa.
            lastLocation = location
            val currentLatLng = LatLng(location.latitude, location.longitude)
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(currentLatLng, 17f))

            val mTxt = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.mTxtMsg)  //objeto que vai receber o endereço
            mTxt.setText(getAddress(currentLatLng, location.latitude, location.longitude))  //coloca o endereço dentro do objeto através deste método. 

        }
    }
}
```

Por fim vamos criar o método que realmente busca os dados do endereço do usuário.

private fun getAddress(latLng: LatLng, lat: Double, long: Double) :String {
        // 1
        val geocoder = Geocoder(this)
        val addresses: List?
        val address: Address?
        var addressText = ""

```
    try {
        // 2
        addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude, 1)
        // 3
        if (null != addresses && !addresses.isEmpty()) {
            address = addresses[0]
            val mFullAddress = Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault())
            var mUserCidade = ""
            if (addresses[0].locality == null){ //as vezes a cidade vem em locality e outras em subAdminArea, então precisamos fazer essa verificação
                mUserCidade = addresses[0].subAdminArea
            } else {
                mUserCidade = addresses[0].locality
            }
            val mUserEstado = addresses[0].adminArea
            val mUserBairro = addresses[0].subLocality
            val mUserNumeroCasa = addresses[0].subThoroughfare
            val mUserRua = addresses[0].thoroughfare
            val mUuserPais = addresses[0].countryName
            val mUserCep = addresses[0].postalCode
            addressText = mUserRua+" nº "+mUserNumeroCasa+", "+mUserBairro+", "+mUserCidade+" - "+mUserEstado
            //user as outras variaveis se quiser usar cep, país, bairro


        }
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        Log.e("MapsActivity", e.localizedMessage)
    }

    return addressText
}
```

Observações: Para este método funcionar você precisa já ter as permissões do usuário para acessar estas informações e também já ter colocado no manifesto.